# Stretch spacing between words doesn`t work

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to increase space in a text in a poster box but it doesn`t work (Name Middlename Lastname). Look what i tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0pt]{geometry}    
\newcommand{\header}[1]{\fontdimen3\font=0.1em #1}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcbposter}[
        poster = {columns=1, rows=1, spacing=0pt},
        boxes = {sharp corners, halign=center, valign=center, boxrule=0pt}
    ]
    \posterbox[colback=black,halign=center]
    {
        name=headbox,
        span=1,
        rowspan=0.10
    }
    {
        \color{white}
    
        \header{Name MiddleName LastName}
    
        \vspace{-7px}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=white] (-5.0, -0.01) rectangle (5.0, 0.01);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{5px}
    }
    \end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Hi - could you add the small amount that is missing from your example to make it compilable (the document class)? Could you also explain a little more where you are trying to add the space?

Comment: you have increased the stretch component (for the whole box, not just the header) but that isn't used here, you could set fontdimen2 the natural length or simpler set `\spaceskip`  but why in `\header` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the last line of a paragraph there is infinite stretch from `\parfillskip` so finite stretch in word space is not normally used.

You could instead set fontdimen2 the natural length, but it is simpler to set `\spaceskip` which is used instead of the font dimen if it is non zero.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Name MiddleName LastName


{\fontdimen3\font=0.1em
Name MiddleName LastName

}



{\fontdimen2\font=0.1em
Name MiddleName LastName

}


{\fontdimen2\font=0.7em
Name MiddleName LastName

}




{\spaceskip=.7em
Name MiddleName LastName

}



\end{document}
```

So in general you could use `\fontdimen2` or `\spaceskip` but here `tcolorbox` has already  set `\spaceskip` as you can check with `\showthe \spaceskip` which shows `3.33298pt` so the font dimen are not used.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why only "\spaceskip" works? in my newcommand (\header) called at posterbox.

Comment: @BrendonRusPeres I added a final paragraph about that

Comment: thanks! I understood now. I am newbie at Latex, but trying to improve my skills